# Prevent gitlab multiple pipelines for push using --follow-tags option

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm looking for a way to prevent Gitlab from creating multiple pipeline for a single push command (skipping is not an option for now), for example:

```bash
git add .
git commit -m "Patch something"
git tag -a v1.0.2 -m "Releasing version v1.0.2"
git push --follow-tags
```

The current Gitlab behaviour is to create two pipelines, one because I pushed to a branch and a second because I added a tag.

For the sake of the example, suppose my pipeline has 2 stages:

- `tests` (that runs both on regular push and tags)
- `deploy` (which runs only on tags).

Which, in this case, means **`tests` will run twice** for this push (once in each pipeline).

I used to have two commands for this: `git push -o ci.skip && git push --tag` which wasn't good either because I had a skipped pipeline and there is a [bug with badges and skipped pipelines in Gitlab](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/326513). Because of this bug, I had badges in `unknown` state on every tag (eventhough the pipeline did succeed).

Notice that I want `tests` to run on both pushes and tags, I just don't want them to happen twice for the same push.

For now I just accept that some of my stages will run twice on the same codebase because I favor the badge being correct. But I would love to avoid using ressources for no reason. My current pipeline looks like this:

```yaml
stages:
    - tests
    - deploy

tests:
    stage: tests
    script:
        - echo "Tests"

k8s-stage:
    stage: deploy
    script:
        - echo "Staging"
    only:
        - tags
```

I've read a bit about the [workflow keyword](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/workflow.html), but I don't understand how it could be used in this case. I guess the solution is here, but I can't see it.

There is a related issue [here on gitlab](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/14548) but it seems unresolved.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I get your problem right and this goes in the intended direction. [According to GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#avoid-duplicate-pipelines), making use of the `workflow` feature OR being as precise as possible with your job rules are the options you have. So for the latter mentioned option for instance, a minimalistic `.gitlab-ci.yml` could look as follows:

```yaml
stages:
 - tests
 - deploy

my_test_job:
  stage: tests
  script:
    - ./gradlew clean build #sample command that would run tests in Java project managed with Gradle
  rules:
   - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG == null && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != "merge_request_event"

my_deploy_job:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - helm install <MY_HELM_RELEASE_NAME> -n <MY_K8S_NAMESPACE> #some sample deploy command via Helm (to a Kubernetes cluster)
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != "merge_request_event"
```

For the sake of simplicity, each stage has only one job in the example above. You should surely adjust the job rules according to your needs. Be aware that changing the job rules would have an impact on their execution logic/behavior and might again cause duplicated pipelines to occur.

Configuring the rules for the two jobs as demonstrated above, the jobs would behave the following way:

1. **my_test_job**: Only runs, when no tag is set AND the trigger of the job was NOT a merge request event (such as creation or update of / push to an already open merge request) => Hence, it would only for branch pipelines
2. **my_deploy_job**: Only runs, when a tag is set AND the trigger of the job was NOT a merge request event => Would only run for tag events

Hence, there should be no duplicated pipelines anymore.

Comment: I haven't stated this explcitely, but I want tests to run on both regular push and tags. Unless I'm mistaking I don't think this solution would achieve what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to make use of [workflow rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/workflow.html)

This is what I did for my pipeline

```
workflow:
  rules:
    # push to default branch
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"
    # mergerequest for the branch - possibly to target only MR against the default branch
    - if: $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
    # manual trigger via RunPipeline
    - if: $DEPLOY_ENVIRONMENT && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"
```

After adding workflow rules, you also need to tweak rules per Job to achieve exactly what you need.

Please be aware that `CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE` is different if you make use of a [downstream pipeline with a trigger](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/downstream_pipelines.html?tab=Parent-child+pipeline)
Eg. the original event is `CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE=merge_request_event`, triggered child has `CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE=parent_pipeline`. This can be really annoying because at that point you basically need to maintain your own state and ass arguments eg. `PARENT_PIPELINE_ID`

Additionally, you could try to make use of new feature inputs https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/inputs.html - but IMO the implementation is very poor compared to what GitHub offers. As I see it, Gitlab started with a lot of great ideas but after the introduction of GitHub pipelines, it fell far behind.